# Automating vba code window

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file, batch-processing

how to write a batch command to print text contents in vba code editor window similar to printing contents in a notepad using echo command?

```
echo This is for just testing > test.txt
```

The above command will create a notepad file called 'test' with contents 'This is for just testing'.Similarly how to write contents in vba code window.

Thanks in advance

Comment: well, this question does not really show any research and it's a bit unclear... Start by searching about it, see if [**THIS HELPS**](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/programmatically-create-a-module-and-write-to-a-it/)

Comment: @mehow I edited the question.Please reopen if the question is clear

Comment: @Code_Kid I still don't understand. Isn't the link given helpful?

Comment: @mehow Ok.How can i write the following code in vba code window from command line. Sub test()  Sheet1.cells(1,1)=1 End Sub

Comment: @mehow Sorry I am a beginner could not understand the link you have posted

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `myModule` exists:

```
Sub echo(s As String)
    Call Application.VBE.VBProjects(1).VBComponents("myModule").CodeModule.AddFromString(s)
End Sub
```

You will probably need to activate macro editiion in the Trust Center:
File > Option > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Macro Settings
Check `Trust access to the VBA project object model`